# Example smtp dsn bounce messages for testing

Tags: smtp, email-bounces, dsn

I'm working on building a feature for a larger system that will be able to parse and react to dsn bounce messages received from all different types of smtp servers.

It be great to test the code I write by reading a bunch of txt files containing examples of the types of bounce messages that might be encountered out in the wild ;-)

Anyone have any suggestions on where to find a bunch of test dsn messages lying around? Or any thoughts on how to create some good test data?

UPDATE: I found a ton of good test data inside this project: https://github.com/rjbs/mail-deliverystatus-bounceparser/tree/master/t/corpus

Comment: Send out messages to made-up users at domains chosen at random...

Comment: Thanks @Ward, I've been doing this and it's working pretty well.

Comment: Feel free to accept and/or upvote now that I made the comment an answer...  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The comment was somewhat flippant, but it's what I'd do.  Since you say it's working, I thought I'd make it an actual answer.)

Send out messages to made-up users at domains chosen (almost) at random.  You could use:

- big companies (Google, MS, etc.)
- companies that friends work at (slightly mis-type their names)
- companies/domains that you have any email from

In order to get a responses from a range of mailers, you'll have to look at headers of all your existing email messages and see what other people are using.

Comment: Thanks, @Ward. Yeah, this is the first time I've dug this deep under the hood of how email works and so just wondering if there might be something I was missing. But this seems like the best/most obvious solution. I think I was over-thinking it.